# Why when I highlight items on CSS Zen Garden, it highlights different areas?

Tags: html, css

I asked a question like this yesterday, but I seem to not understand much about the reason why the css shows this location. For example:

[example1 http://puu.sh/k5r57/6e59005bdd.jpg](http://puu.sh/k5r57/6e59005bdd.jpg)

Selecting an image further down the DOM, suddenly selects the topmost banner, but selecting its children selects location where I would have expected that to be judging by the flow of the box-model.

Or,

[example2 http://puu.sh/k5rkp/b07bdcd576.jpg](http://puu.sh/k5rkp/b07bdcd576.jpg)

Highlighting the parent div 'Requirements' does not require the entire contents the box would originally select.

Is it something in the CSS why I don't understand how the box model in this website works?

Comment: And the code is in a crystal ball?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Zen Garden is a CSS experiment site. The whole point of it is for authors to take a single fixed unchanging HTML page and use CSS to restyle it; the idea being to demonstrate how much power CSS has even without you having to modify your HTML code.

Some of the page designs created this way for the Zen Garden site look wildly different from each other, and they achieve that by using all kinds of CSS tricks to move elements around the page.

In short, the behaviour you've described is pretty much what I'd expect from the CSS Zen Garden site.

It is intended for you to learn from; if you're struggling with it, try reading the CSS source code; there may be useful comments there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a div with class 'clear' before closing the tag like below

In this the clear should have the style like below

```css
<style>
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div>Hello JDudez
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because of using float to the elements so if we use clear then it will aligns the content accordingly